# Creating a JSON struct from available rows after Group By in PySpark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to group by customer_id, so that I can collect the key/value pair of field_name and field_value as a JSON struct. So, for example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
customerID | field_name | field_value
-------------------------------------
A          | age        | 20
A          | sex        | M
A          | country    | US
B          | country    | US
B          | age        | 34
c          | sex        | F
```

All columns in the DataFrame have a String data type. What I want is this:

```
customerID | custom_attributes
-------------------------------------
A          | {'age':'20', 'sex': 'M', 'country':'US'}
B          | {'age':'34', 'country':'US'}
c          | {'sex':'F'}
```

This is what I tried:

```
test = (data
        .groupBy('customer_id')
        .agg(
          collect_list(struct(col('field_name'), col('field_value'))).alias('custom_attributes'))
       )
```

But this gets me as far as getting an array that I dont know how to flatten:

```
customer_id | custom_attributes
--------------------------------
A           | [{'field_name':'sex', 'field_value':'M'},
            |  {'field_name':'age', 'field_value':'34'},
            |  {'field_name':'country', 'field_value':'US'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a pivot here:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = (df.groupBy('customerID')
         .pivot('field_name')
         .agg(F.first('field_value'))
         .select('customerID', F.to_json(F.struct('age', 'country', 'sex')).alias('custom_attributes'))
         .orderBy('customerID')
      )

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-------------------------------------+
|customerID|custom_attributes                    |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
|A         |{"age":"20","country":"US","sex":"M"}|
|B         |{"age":"34","country":"US"}          |
|c         |{"sex":"F"}                          |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I thought about doing that but wouldn't it create a ton of null values inside the json for a customer ID if given field is not there? So for example, customer C, would have a custom_attributes like so: {"sex":"F", "age":null, "country":null}?

Comment: @FrankPinto no, by default null fields are not included for `to_json`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I ended modifying the code just a bit because the columns that result from the pivot are not always going to be the same, so I swapped the argument in the F.struct with a df2.columns and some other logic. The only issue I have left is that it's that the custom_attributes column results in a String column. Is there a way to get that as a JSON?

Comment: you can remove `to_json`, but that would result in null fields because a column can only contain structs with the same number and type of fields.

Comment: I think I can deal with this later on my in my process, so it won't be necessary. Thanks for the help.